# Is there a way to login into django admin using external 3rd party authentication

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-admin

I have a requirement to migrate from php to django. I was authentication the user over a rest call's response in php. Where I would pass the user name and password and it would tell me if the user is authenticated or not in a form of JSON response.

I would like to make use of the same concept here with django admin, I have seen the custom-authentication that django provides, in which it creates a new user into django's user tables after checking the authenticity of the user from my existing table. But that is not what i am looking for.

And this rest call is not any of the social websites but a different stand alone system itself. So cant make use of the different plugins available on google search.

Comment: Start here maybe: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/ ?

Comment: From there: "The Django admin system is tightly coupled to the Django User object described at the beginning of this document. For now, the best way to deal with this is to create a Django User object for each user that exists for your backend (e.g., in your LDAP directory, your external SQL database, etc.) You can either write a script to do this in advance, or your authenticate method can do it the first time a user logs in."